# Can you create more than one controller to override the same Magento core controller?

Tags: php, magento, controller

Can you create more than one controller to override the same Magento core controller?For example, Can I create two modules, in each module, create an AccountController.php to override the Magento's core AccountController in Mage/Customer?
Will it create any conflicts if two modules are depending on the save core module and overriding the same controller, of course each controller will overriding different actions in the core controller.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create more than one module that both extend the same core controller.

First you will want to include the core controller then overload only the specific functions you want.

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Namespace_Module1_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
     public function indexAction(){

       //this will overload the index action for the core customer AccountController

     }
}
```

Repeat this with each module you make and only overload the actions you wish to change. For example if you wanted the second module to overload the save action you would do.

```
require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php';
class Namespace_Module2_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController
{
     public function saveAction(){

       //this will overload the save action for the core customer AccountController 
       //this will also leave your index action overload from the other module in place

     }
}
```

Comment: But if both module using same function then how will it work? both or one will work ? or any confiliction/error will be occur?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but I believe that If both modules define a function of the same name then one of them will always be ignored (the one whose config.xml file was loaded last will win, and I _think_ 3rd party modules are loaded alphabetically). If, however, they both rely on a common function inherited from the core controller, that's fine. They can coexist like that.